# Python 3 | Mutithreading starts before thread.start() is decleared

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

Trying to have 2 methods running at once. One is a timer method and the other writes data to a CSV. I am trying to use Treading to run them both at once, but the thread starts before it is called.

Code;

```
 with open("C:\\ProgramData\\Example.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
        array = for line in file.readlines()]))

    fieldnames = 'Col1','Col2','Col3'
    with open("C:\\ProgramData\\example.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
     writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
     writer.writerow(fieldnames)
     writer.writerows(array)
     csvfile.close()

def timer():
    import time
    import sys

    time_start = time.time()
    seconds = 0
    minutes = 0

    while True:
        try:
            sys.stdout.write("\r{minutes} Minutes {seconds} Seconds".format(minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(1)
            seconds = int(time.time() - time_start) - minutes * 60
            if seconds >= 60:
                minutes += 1
                seconds = 0
        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    print("Not running")
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=timer())
    print("clearly running")
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=regx())
    t1.setName('t1')
    t2.setName('t2')

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
  # pool =Pool(processes=2)
  # pool.map(timer(),regx())
```

The output from the console;

```
Not running
2 Minutes 32 Seconds
Process finished with exit code -1
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Thanks

Comment: When you use `target=timer()`, the `timer` method is executed intermediately, and the result is assigned to the thread `target`, Try `target=timer` instead (similar for `regx`).

Comment: @John Anderson I tried it like this `t1 = threading.Thread= timer()` is this what you mean? If so it still only starts one of them still....

Comment: No, I mean `t1 = threading.Thread(target=timer)`. Don't use `()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `()` unless you want to run the method immediately. If you want to reference the method itself (like to pass it to `Thread`), leave off the `()`.
Try this code:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    print("Not running")
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=timer)
    print("clearly running")
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=regx)
    t1.setName('t1')
    t2.setName('t2')

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Comment: Changed it to Muti Processing and it works a dream, Thanks again